# Firebase emails not sending after introducing a template

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-extensions

I've been using the send emails with Firebase extension to trigger emails when a mail document is created, rendering a long HTML string.

I just recently introduced a template, and ever since that happened, the emails are not sending (but the mail document says it was a success, and the function logs also say it was a success).

I don't think it's an issue with my ISP, as the emails were sending fine before I introduced a template.

Are there any possible issues that could lead to this that wouldn't show up in the error logs?

Here is a screenshot of the mail document, as well as the HTML in the template, if useful:

[image]

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test Email Sample</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width: 100%; vertical-align: center">
  <table bgcolor=#000000 style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;" class="home-container">

    <!-- Header Section -->
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;
      padding: 36px;">
        <table style="width: 100%;">
          <tr style="text-align: left">
            <td style="text-align: left; width: 40px;">
              <a href="https://www.lattisapp.com">
              <img alt="image" src="https://www.lattisapp.com/images/lattisicon.jpg"
                style="width: 40px;
                height: 40px;
                object-fit: cover;
                border-color: #000000;
                border-width: 1px;
                border-radius: 8px;"/></a>
            </td>
            <td style="margin: 0 auto;"><h1 style="
              text-align: left;
              color: #fff;
              padding-left: 8px;
              font-size: 30px;
              text-transform: capitalize;
              font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;">Lattis</h1></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- Rest of the header content -->
        <table style="width: 100%;
        gap: 32px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-start;">
          <tr>
            <td><h1 style="color: #fff;
              max-width: 600px;
              text-align: center;
              font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
              line-height: 1.6;">You&apos;ve been invited:</h1></td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="border-spacing: 32px">
            <td><h2 style="color: #fff;
              font-size: 20px;
              text-align: center;
              line-height: 1.6;
              font-family:'Inter',sans-serif;">{{senderName}} is inviting you to join {{groupTitle}} on Lattis{{inviteMessage}}</i></h2></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <span style="color: #fff;
              font-size: 16px;
              font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;">Instructions: Download Lattis with the links below. Copy your invite code, and paste it in during registration to join this group.</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- Hero button list -->
        <table style="flex: 0 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;"
          class="hero-button-list">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <a href="https://apps.apple.com/us/app/lattis-goal-habit-tracker/id6470149396">
                <img alt="image"
                  src="https://www.lattisapp.com/images/app-store-badge.png"
                  style="width: 200px;
                  object-fit: cover;
                  padding: 16px;" class="apple-button" />
              </a>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pagefamdesigns.lattis">
                <img alt="image" src="https://play.google.com/intl/en_us/badges/static/images/badges/en_badge_web_generic.png"
                  style="width: 240px;
                  object-fit: cover;
                  padding: 16px;" class="android-button" />
              </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- Hero invite code instructions -->
        <table style="flex: 0 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
        align-items: center;
        text-align: center;
        justify-content: center;"
          class="hero-invite-code-instructions">
          <tr>
            <td style="color: #fff; font-size: 16px;
            font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif; margin: 0 auto;" class="standard-text-dark">
              <span>Your invite code is:</span><br />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- Invite code container -->
        <table style="
        width: 200px;
        height: 50px;
        display: flex;
        text-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        border-color: #dedcdc;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 2px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        background-color: #868585;
        margin: 0 auto;"
          class="invite-code-container">
          <tr>
            <td style="width: 200px;
            color: #000000;
            font-size: 24px;
            line-height: 1.6;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0 auto;
            font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif; "
              class="invite-code">{{inviteCode}}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>

    <!-- Details Section -->
    <table bgcolor="#dedcdc" style="text-align: center; width: 100%; max-width: 600px; padding-left: 36px; padding-right: 36px;
    margin: 0 auto;">
    <tr>
      <td
        style="flex: 0 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 600px;
        height: auto;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        "
        class="details-section">
        <table style="width: 100%;">
          <tr>
            <td style="width: 100%; display: flex; max-width: 600px; flex-direction: column; padding-bottom: 64px; justify-content: center;"
              class="details-content">
              <!-- Group Info Content -->
              <td style="flex: 1; display: flex; align-items: flex-start; flex-direction: column; justify-content: flex-start;"
                class="details-group-info">
                <tr>
                  <td><h1 style="color: #000000;
                    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
                    font-size: 28px;
                    ">Group Details</h1></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><h2 style="font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
                  font-size: 24px;">Title: {{groupTitle}}</h2></td>
                </tr>
                {{groupDescription}}
              {{memberList}}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <!-- Footer Section -->
    <table bgcolor=#000000 style="margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
    ">
    <tr>
                  <td style="color: #fff;
                  font-size: 14px;
                  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
                  margin: 0 auto;
                  padding: 48px;" class="standard-text-dark">Copyright 2024 Page Fam
                    Designs, LLC., All Rights Reserved.</td>
                </tr>
              </td>
            
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your email is being received by the recipient email server (250 OK). That does not mean the email will be delivered by that server to the recipient. If the recipient does not receive the email, you have a different type of problem. Use an online service to check for "spaminess" of your email. Make sure you have at least a DNS SPF record. I also recommend configuring DMARC and DKIM. Send an email to one of your accounts and see if it goes to SPAM. Add more details to your question as the template is not causing a problem, but the content might.

Comment: Thanks. It's definitely an issue with the content - something about adding this raw html is messing it up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77958953/sending-email-with-firebase-using-template-can-you-get-html-rendered-when-sp

Comment: I'm not sure if that belonged in a separate question since it turns out my issue is actually something else.

Comment: And what is the something else?